# Requesting a patch for Evolution to access iCloud Mail

Tags: release-hera, gnome, evolution

iCloud Mail can no longer be accessed via GNOME Evolution:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evolution/-/issues/1468

This has been patched for Fedora:

https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/mcrha/eds-icloud-mail/

This has been reported for Ubuntu:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution-data-server/+bug/1925742

Per the above:

*"We will include the fix in the next updates though"*

As it is unknown how long it may take for the next updates to roll out, a patch would be appreciated.

This was discussed here:

https://mail.gnome.org/archives/evolution-list/2021-April/date.html

https://mail.gnome.org/archives/evolution-list/2021-April/msg00088.html

Per the above:

*On Sat, 2021-04-24 at 20:59 +0000, Steve via evolution-list wrote:

```
I see you have pushed a Redhat patch through for Evolution.
How would one go about getting similar for Debian >> Linux Mint?
```

You'd contact the packagers of your distribution as they provide the
packages for the distribution that you are using.

Cheers,
andre*

So, I am submitting this request as a way of initiating contact to the packagers of the distribution I use - Elementary OS - to request this patch.

Thanks in advance.

elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera
Built on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Linux 5.4.0-72-generic
GTK 3.22.30

Evolution
3.40.0 (by Flathub.org)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, really frustrating that there are no work around or solutions for Icloud users with gnome/evolution mail servers.

no problem with the caldev or other twofactor systems of other mail providers but @icloud.com